# Android: Google API map problem

Tags: android, google-maps, mapactivity

I am using Google Maps API level 7 (which corresponds to Android 2.1) to display a map on my app. The code displays the map perfectly when I run it using Android 1.1, but when I run it using Google Maps API 7, I only see X's all over the place. I have to say that the map displays correctly for only 1 second then disappears. The code is exactly the same that I am using in Android 1.1 and Google Maps API 7, so why would this problem occur?

Comment: Android 1.1? Why would you think code that was written for 1.1 even remotely work for 2.1?

Comment: so you think it's code related? The other functionalities of the app work perfectly though, it's only the map that is not displayed properly

Comment: @user522559: The point is that effectively there are no devices on the planet that run Android 1.1.

Comment: so you mean that code written in 1.1 won't upload on any device?